# Switch views with navigation controller using UISegmentedControl

Tags: swift, uinavigationcontroller

I have a UISegmentedControl which switches 2 View controllers. I want my view controllers will be root view controller for navigation controller. I create them like this:

```
    filialView = (UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "FilialList") as! FilialListController).view

    viewContainer.addSubview(filialView)

    
    let navCon = (UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MyScheduleNav") as! MyScheduleNavController)
    
    myScheduleView = navCon.view      
    viewContainer.addSubview(myScheduleView)

    self.viewContainer.bringSubviewToFront(self.filialView)
    
    self.viewContainer.layoutIfNeeded()
```

But when I open another view controller from `myScheduleView` using segue there is no navigation bar on that view.

Could you help me please?

Comment: check if `self.naviagtionController` is nil?

Comment: No, it is not nil

Comment: Actually I find your whole way very suspecious. Why aren't you using rootVC for that navigationcontroller.